# Grab certain variable from model to model relation in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to grab a variable in my user model that's in relation to authorization model. The following works in Rails console but not sure how to translate that into the user.rb model since it keeps giving me error that it has to be a symbol or string. Doing `to_s` isn't correct outcome.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_many :authorizations

    def social
        user = User.current
        token = user.authorizations.pluck(:token).to_s
    end

end
```

my authorizations model also looks like this;

```
class Authorization < ActiveRecord::Base

    belongs_to :user

end
```

I've tried doing

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

    def social
        user = User.current
        token = user.authorizations.select(:token).to_s
    end

end
```

Doing this below in console works but not when I'm doing `user.authorizations`

```
auth = Authorization.where(:user_id => '54').token
```

but everything comes incorrect because it either has brackets or `\` slashes within it.

Comment: Have you defined the `has_many: authorizations` in User model ?

Comment: yes.. also in my console doing `user = User.find('58')` 58 being the user id and then doing 'user.authorizations' will bring the right record. Then I thought I would be able to do also `user.authorizations.token` but I get error `undefined method "token" for #<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x007f9b464233b0>` however token is within authorizations and `user.authorizations` does show all the columns including token.

Comment: Can you try `user.authorizations.collect(&:token)` ?

Comment: is User.current nil?

Comment: @AnkitG if I do that and run it live or test, I get error `Invalid token specified: ["some token number here"] must be a string or symbol.` so it works to some point.

Comment: so collect must be returning you a array of tokens, you may have to pick the first i think

Comment: doing `user.authorizations.collect(&:token).to_s` works but still prints something incorrectly because it looks like this `"[\"some number here\"]"` and I'm looking for just `some number here` without quotes, brackets or slashes..

Comment: collect(&:token) returns a array and doing to_s on array is not right, you have to pick the first element

Comment: @AnkitG how do I pick the first element, it only returns `["some number here"] ... one, not more then one..

Comment: git it.... `.first` will do then?

Comment: user.authorizations.collect(&:token).first.to_s , give it a shot :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62202/discussion-between-ankitg-and-user2419316).

Comment: @AnkitG the following works `user.authorizations.collect(&:token).first` ... if you want to put that into answer, give you the credit for the answer on stackoverflow with a vote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's returning the `user.authorizations` then do a

```
user.authorizations.collect(&:token).first.to_s
```

pluck is on the db level. It will only query the particular field.

Answer (score 0):

You are close with:

```
token = user.authorizations.pluck(:token).to_s
```

To align with Like @AnkitG's answer it would need to be

```
token = user.authorizations.pluck(:token).first.to_s
```

If you are going to consistently have a single authorization you may want to change the relationship from

```
has_many :authorizations
```

to

```
has_one :authorization
```

This way you can:

```
user.authorization.token
```